# Best cache size for iOS apps

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, caching, disk

I'm currently developing an application that loads lots of images from the internet and saves them locally (I'm using SDURLCache). However, old images have get removed from the disk again so I was wondering what the best cache size is.
The advantage of a big cache is obviously that more images get saved which leads to better UX.
The disadvantage is that images need a lot of space and the user will run out of disk space faster. The size I am thinking of is 20MB. It seems so big to me though so I'm asking you what you're opinion is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the smallest iDevices have 8GB of storage, I don't think a 20MB cache is too big, especially if it significantly improves the performance of the app. Also, keep in mind the huge advantage a network cache can have for battery life, since network usage is very expensive in battery time.

Determining the ideal size however is hard without some more information. How often is the same picture accessed? How large is each picture (i.e. how many pictures can 20MB hold). How often will images need to be removed from the cache to add new ones?

If you are constantly changing the images in the cache, it could actually have an adverse effect on the battery life due to the increased disk usage.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really improve the performance. It rather improves the memory usage so it the app doesn't crash if there are many pictures loaded. One picture gets accessed about 2 times. And in 10 MB might fit like 15 or 20 pictures.

Comment: Ahh I see, well if it's purely to keep images out of memory, then you just need to determine how many images you can safely keep in memory at once without hitting out of memory errors on older devices (X), then find out the maximum number of pictures you will ever need to load at once (Y), and the average size of each picture (Z). Then your appropriate cache size is simply (Y - X) * Z, give or take a few MB. If that is too large, then you may need to rethink the way your app works.

Comment: Also I'm not familiar with SDURLCache, so if it is an all or nothing thing (i.e. all pictures in memory or all cached), then the equation is simply Y * Z. Though you could always write a custom solution to fit your needs exactly.

Comment: Thanks bud, gonna try this out.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to decide on an appropriate cache size is to test. Run the app under Instruments to measure both performance and battery usage. Keep increasing the cache size until you can't discern a difference in performance. That's the largest size you'd need, at least under the test conditions. Once you've established that size, reduce the size until performance is just barely acceptable to determine the smallest acceptable size.

The *right* size is somewhere between those two sizes, depending on what you think is important. If you can't determine a *right* size, then either pick a size or add a slider to the app's settings to let the user decide. (I'd avoid making it user-adjustable if you can -- users shouldn't have to think about such things.)